# How can I sort the banner list with each `Sort Order`?

Tags: magento2, admin, slider, banner-slider

In the Magento admin site.
I go to Manage `Sliders > Choose to edit some banner > click show banner` list

How can I sort the banner list with each Sort Order?

Actually, When it shows on the real website, it shows by I sorted.

But in the list of the banner, it sorts by an ID created from Magento.

I need to sort the banner using sort order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find you collection file and You can try something like below

```
$bannerColletion = $this->_bannerFactory->getCollection();
$bannerColletion ->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

`setOrder` is use for sorting